# KML icon size google maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using a KML custom Icon Like so:

```
        <Style id='icon-1073'>
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.1</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/1073-biz-real-estate.png</href>
            </Icon>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>
```

but I seem unable to use large icons... 
if i use a 100px by 100px it still scales it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [KML reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps), the scale tag is not supported in Google Maps or the Google Maps Javascript API.

```
<scale> no
```

Options:

- [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2FSO_scaledIcon2x.kml&hl=en&ll=21.595981,71.323199&spn=0.002319,0.003484&sll=21.59615,71.323242&sspn=0.002319,0.003484&t=h&z=19) (scales icons to fixed size)
- [Google Maps Javascript API v3 KmlLayer](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/SO_scaledIcon2x.kml) (scales icons to fixed size)
- [geoxml3 third party KML parser](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/SO_scaledIcon2x.kml) (supports scaled icons, but renders KML as native Google Maps Javascript API v3 object, so will have performance issues for complex KML) ([geoxml3 project page](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/))

KML loaded by the links above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
<Style id='icon-1073'>
  <IconStyle>
    <scale>2.0</scale>
    <Icon>
      <href>http://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/1073-biz-real-estate.png</href>
    </Icon>
  </IconStyle>
</Style>
<Placemark>
  <name><![CDATA[]]></name>
  <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
  <styleUrl>#icon-1073</styleUrl>
  <Point>
    <extrude>1</extrude>
    <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
    <coordinates>71.3232421875,21.596150576461437,0</coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```