# Google Maps JS API - Pixellated pins

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am building a local map with custom pin icons using a KMZ file generated by MyMaps - https://www.google.com.au/maps/d/

Unfortunately the pin icons look very pixellated:

Test at:
https://www.veronica.io/xmas.html

The size of the pin icons is 100x100px. I've tried swapping out the images in the KMZ file itself using 7zip to compare - with both 72dpi and 300dpi versions, all at the 100x100px size, alas no difference.

Pins are styled by:

```
<Style id="icon-ci-1-labelson-nodesc">
  <IconStyle>  
    <Icon>
     <href>images/location-icon-1.png</href>
    </Icon>
  </IconStyle>

  <BalloonStyle>
    <text><![CDATA[<h3>$[name]</h3>]]></text>
  </BalloonStyle>
</Style>
```

I have also tried scaling `<scale>1</scale>`, but that doesn't make any difference.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Without sharing runnable code and without sharing the icon, I doubt you'll get any help.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps Javascript API KML Layer scales all icons to a fixed size (32x32).  That scaling is causing your pixelation.

Related questions:

- [Marker scales greater than 1 ignored when using a KML layer with the Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35487647/marker-scales-greater-than-1-ignored-when-using-a-kml-layer-with-the-google-maps)
- [KML icon size google maps API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21393101/kml-icon-size-google-maps-api)

Make your icons 32x32 so they don't get scaled.

Comment: The problem is that this also doesn't work (I've tried it based on a previous answer and should've mentioned that..). I've updated the images in the with 32x32px versions and set scaling to 1.0.

The KMZ file is exported directly from MyMaps where icons are scaled to 60x60px. The default icons bundled with the KMZ itself are also 60x60, which I've also tried...and the same thing happens.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the KMZ where you tried that? (32x32 icons with a scale of 1)

Comment: Correction, icons are 64x64px*. Albeit, still the same problem remains at scale of 1, with 64x64px files.

32x32px KMZ (inc, KML and images) is here:

https://www.veronica.io/au-xmas-lights-32.kmz

Comment: Those icons [look OK to me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=https://www.veronica.io/au-xmas-lights-32.kmz), what browser/platform do you see them pixelated?

Comment: Edge 42.17134.1.0, Firefox 63.0.3, Chrome 70.0.3538.102 on Win10 Pro 1803. 

The only thing that I can think of is that it's a pixel density problem, which is corrected in Google Maps (by Maps serving 2x scaled images for higher resolution displays)/which is purged once the images are exported into a KMZ file (and the KMZ file only serving 1x images).

I am on a 4500x3000px monitor at the moment - tried downscaling to 1920x1080px, though that didn't help me either.

Do the images look crisp for you, or only slightly pixelated?

Comment: ...it appears this hasn't been documented a lot, but I _did_ find it's there:  
  
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822544   
  
Using the Maps API for Javascript works perfectly fine, but using the KML dump is necessary when dealing with this amount of pins.